# Symfony2: FOSUserBundle - SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: during user registration

Tags: php, forms, symfony, verification

How can I verify that the username and the mail aren't already present in my database before the insertion.

I tried with the `isValid()` method  but it doesn't work.

My Entity:

```
 <?php

namespace Fiducial\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateurPortail")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Fiducial\UserBundle\Repository\UtilisateurPortailRepository")
 */
class UtilisateurPortail extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
```

Inside my controller:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    if($userManager->findUserByUsername($user->getUsername()) != null) {
        $message = 'Nom d\'utilisateur déjà utilisé';
    } elseif($userManager->findUserByEmail($user->getEmail()) != null) {
        $message = 'Email déjà utilisé';
    } else {
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        $message = 'Utilisateur ajouté !';
    }
}
```

I get this error/exception when I try to save a user with a username that already exists to database:

> An
>   exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO utilisateurPortail
>   (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt,
>   password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token,
>   password_requested_at, roles, credentials_expired,
>   credentials_expire_at, id, raisonsociale, nom, prenom, fonction,
>   envoiSMS, telephone, premiere_connexion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["dd",
>   "dd", "a@p.fr", "a@p.fr", 1, "fhaqicni2sgko4o8s4804oo8g48wcgw",
>   "tdsZpiC1Tzbh5mAVf23uyp9hnXDv39eEXzBh4/P3/DECu5z3QbqGHJjSSy6ccpir6T35rS5r043WSacBqazJNA==",
>   null, 0, 0, null, null, null, "a:1:{i:0;s:16:\"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN\";}",
>   0, null, 8, "sdfsdq", "aaa", "aaa", "dsfvsdf", 1, "3333333333", 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERREUR: la valeur d'une clé
>   dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « uniq_1e48ea092fc23a8 » DETAIL:
>   La clé « (username_canonical)=(dd) » existe déjà.

Answer (score 1):

"username_canonical" is the validated by FOSBundle username, so You need to rewrite your code

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    if($userManager->findUserByUsernameCanonical($user->getUsernameCanonical()) != null) {
        $message = 'Nom d\'utilisateur déjà utilisé';
    } elseif($userManager->findUserByEmail($user->getEmail()) != null)      {
        $message = 'Email déjà utilisé';
    } else {
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        $message = 'Utilisateur ajouté !';
    }
 }
```

And function

```
public function getUsernameCanonical()
{
     // Better to assign this util by __construct or as parameter to this function
     $canonicalizer = FOS\UserBundle\Util\Canonicalizer();
     return canonicalizer->canonicalize($this->getUsername());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`UniqueEntity`**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) validation constraint to check wether a *username* or *email* already exists in your database.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="table")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Fiducial\UserBundle\Repository\UtilisateurPortailRepository")
 *
 * -> Add this annotation
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"username", "email"}
 * )
 */
class UtilisateurPortail extends BaseUser
```